# Theoretical basis of consumer confidence

Tags: theory, behavioral-macroeconomics

I have read several papers on the formation of consumer confidence, how it is measured and also its role in predicting economic outcomes empirically.

But I haven't come across any theoretical model of either the formation of consumer confidence, or even any model where they are taken to be given and whose influence on other variables can be deduced.

What is the currently most widely accepted theoretical model of consumer confidence? Any good papers/ books/ notes/ lectures to study?